# how to call function inside a function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to call a function with setTimeout() inside another function and I keep getting this error:

`hi is not defined`

This is the code.

```
hello("hi");
function hello(a)
{
    hi(a);
    function hi(b)
    {
        console.log(b);
        c = setTimeout('hi("' + b + '")', 50)
    }
}
```

One `"hi"` is being logged, but then it just stops. I believe problem is in this part: `c = setTimeout('hi("' + b + '")', 50)`

Is there a fix without changing function inside function structure?

Comment: You're calling `hi` before you've defined it. (edit: nope...)

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's called hoisting :)

Comment: calling before or after defining hi gave me the same results, so I didn't bother. Similar to duplicate but setTimeout has the child function not the parent. Thank You all though.

Comment: @evolutionxbox your second comment is right. It's duplicate. sorry about that. must have missed it

Comment: @MartynasJakas no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to function as third argument to setTimeout.

```js
hello("hi");
function hello(a)
{
    hi(a);
    function hi(b)
    {
        console.log(b);
        c = setTimeout(hi, 50,b)
    }
}
```

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't let me accept the answer that fast =)

Answer (score 0):

`c = setTimeout( () => hi(b), 50 )` should work.

**Edit** (thanks to @evolutionxbox in the comments)

`c = setTimeout( hi, 50, b )` looks even better.

You're getting this error :

> hi is not defined

at line 4 : `hi(a)`

The execution is not even making it to the timeout part. The timeout itself won't produce an error, but won't do anything either, because `'hi("' + b + '")'` is a string, not a function.

Comment: You can also pass parameters without defining another function... https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: You mean `setTimeout( hi(b), 50 )` ? But then I believe you run into a context problem. If you want to keep the same context, you'll have to do `setTimeout( hi.call(this, b), 50 )`

Comment: I don't think I meant that. I meant `setTimeout(hi, 50, b)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this notation, good to know, thanks.

Comment: Thank both of you. All the answers are perfect.